# iOS UILabel Core Text number of lines

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsattributedstring, core-text

I want to create custom subclass of UILabel which will know current number of displayed lines. As I've understood UILabel automatically changes it's `attributedText` property when one changes either `text` or `font`. So I'm trying to do something like that:

```swift
label.text = "some very long text"
label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 12)

guard let attrStr = label.attributedText else {
    return
}

print(attrStr.lines(fittingWidth: 600).count)

...

extension NSAttributedString {
    func lines(fittingWidth width: CGFloat) -> [String] {
        let attributedString = self
        let framesetter =
            CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(
                attributedString
            )
        let path = CGPath(rect: CGRect(
            x: 0,
            y: 0,
            width: width,
            height: .greatestFiniteMagnitude
        ), transform: nil)
        let frame = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(
            framesetter,
            CFRange(location: 0, length: 0),
            path,
            nil
        )
        let lines = CTFrameGetLines(frame) as! [CTLine]

        var strLines = [String]()
        let nsString = attributedString.string as NSString
        for line in lines {
            let lineRange = CTLineGetStringRange(line)
            let range = NSMakeRange(lineRange.location, lineRange.length)
            strLines.append(nsString.substring(with: range))
        }
        return strLines
    }
}
```

But problem is that `lines(fittingWidth:)` always returns only 1 line for any fitting width when I using label's `attributedText` value. In the same time when I construct `NSAttributedString` myself (by using `text` and `font` property) `lines(fittingWidth:)` returns correct number of lines. What's wrong with built-in `attributedText` value?

Comment: I'm definitely seeing some quirks with `CTFrameGetLines()`. Do you need to work with labels that may have complex `attributedText`? As in, multiple fonts of multiple sizes and paragraph attributes? Or just simple - essentially "plain text" - labels?

Comment: @DonMag, most often I'll be using "plain text" labels with single font, so making a`NSAttributedString` from `text` and `font` properties is acceptable. But I just wanted to make my code universal and being able to handle "multiple fonts of multiple sizes and paragraph attributes".

Comment: OK - from some quick testing, it appears to be more complicated. I found a way to "automate" the conversion from plain text `UILabel` to get an accurate line count... and if you have **set** the `.attributedText` in the label (as opposed to setting the `.text`) `CTFrameGetLines` is reliable --- ***unless*** you have more than one font / size in the label. You might want to take a look at this: https://www.raywenderlich.com/578-core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app -- appears to work well, including support for inline images.

Comment: The solution from here will likely be applicable to your problem too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66987711/size-uitextview-to-fit-multiline-nsattributedstring