# Size UITextView to fit multiline NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview, nsattributedstring, cgsize

I have a `UITextView` containing an `NSAttributedString`. I want to size the text view so that, given a fixed width, it shows the entire string without scrolling.

`NSAttributedString` has a method which allows to compute its bounding rect for a given size

```swift
let computedSize = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 200, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                   options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                   context: nil)
```

But unfortunately it seems not working, since it always returns the height of a single line.

Answer (score 2):

After several attempts, I figured out that the `NSAttributedString` I was setting had `byTruncatingTail` as `lineBreakMode` value for `NSParagraphStyle` (which is the default value we use in our application).

To achieve the desired behaviour I have to change it to `byWordWrapping` or `byCharWrapping`.

```swift
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
// When setting "byTruncatingTail" it returns a single line height
// paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingTail
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
let stringAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [.font: UIFont(name: "Avenir-Book", size: 16.0)!,
                                                       .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle]
let attributedString = NSAttributedString(string: string,
                                          attributes: stringAttributes)
 
let computedSize = attributedString.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: 200, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude),
                                                   options: .usesLineFragmentOrigin,
                                                   context: nil)
computedSize.height
```

Note that when setting the attributed string with `byTruncatingTail` value on a `UILabel` (where  `numberOfLines` value is 0), the string is "automatically" sized to be multiline, which doesn't happen when computing the `boundingRect`.

There are other factors to keep in mind when computing `NSAttributedString` height for use inside a `UITextView` (each one of these can cause the string not to be entirely contained in the text view):

**1. Recompute height when bounds change**

Since height is based on bounds, it should be recomputed when bounds change. This can be achieved using KVO on `bounds` keypath, invalidating the layout when this change.

```swift
observe(\.bounds) { (_, _) in
    invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

In my case I'm invalidating `intrinsicContentSize` of my custom `UITextView` since is the way I size it based on the computed string height.

**2. Use `NSTextContainer` width**

Use `textContainer.width` (instead of `bounds.width`) as the fixed width to use for `boundingRect` method call, since it keeps any `textContainerInset` value into account (although `left` and `right` default values are 0)

**3. Add vertical `textContainerInsets` values to string height**

After computing `NSAttributedString` height we should add `textContainerInsets.top` and `textContainerInsets.bottom` to compute the correct `UITextField` height (their default values is 8.0...)

```swift
override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
    let computedHeight = attributedText.boundingHeight(forFixedWidth: textContainer.size.width)
    return CGSize(width: bounds.width,
                          height: computedHeight + textContainerInset.top + textContainerInset.bottom)
}
```

**4. Remove lineFragmentPadding**

Set 0 as value of `lineFragmentPadding` or, if you want to have it, remember to remove its value from the "fixed width" before computing `NSAttributedString` height

```swift
textView.textContainer.lineFragmentPadding = 0
```

**5. Apply `ceil` to computed height**

The height value returned by `boundingRect` can be fractional, if we use as it is it can potentially cause the last line not to be shown. Pass it to the `ceil` function to obtain the upper integer value, to avoid down rounding.

Answer (score 0):

A possible way to do it, is to subclass `UITextView` to inform you whenever its contentSize did change (~ the size of the text).

```
class MyExpandableTextView: UITextView {

    var onDidChangeContentSize: ((CGSize) -> Void)?
    override var contentSize: CGSize {
        didSet {
            onDidChangeContentSize?(contentSize)
        }
    }
}
```

On the "Parent View":

```
@IBOulet var expandableTextView: MyExpandableTextView! //Do not forget to set the class in the Xib/Storyboard
// or
var expandableTextView = MyExpandableTextView()
```

And applying the effect:

```
expandableTextView. onDidChangeContentSize = { [weak self] newSize in 
   // if you have a NSLayoutConstraint on the height:
   // self?.myExpandableTextViewHeightConstraint.constant = newSize.height
   // else if you play with "frames"
   // self?.expandableTextView.frame.height = newSize.height
}
```